# sparklyr failing with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm hitting a GC overhead limit exceeded error in Spark using `spark_apply`. Here are my specs:

sparklyr v0.6.2
Spark    v2.1.0
4 workers with 8 cores and 29G of memory

The closure `get_dates` pulls data from Cassandra one row at a time. There are about 200k rows total. The process run for about an hour and a half and then given me this memory error.

I've experimented with `spark.driver.memory` which is supposed to increase the heap size, but it's not working.

Any ideas? Usage below

```
> config <- spark_config()
> config$spark.executor.cores = 1 # this ensures a max of 32 separate executors
> config$spark.cores.max = 26 # this ensures that cassandra gets some resources too, not all to spark
> config$spark.driver.memory = "4G"
> config$spark.driver.memoryOverhead = "10g" 
> config$spark.executor.memory = "4G"
> config$spark.executor.memoryOverhead = "1g"
> sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://master",
+                     config = config)
> accounts <- sdf_copy_to(sc, insight %>%
+                           # slice(1:100) %>% 
+                           {.}, "accounts", overwrite=TRUE)
> accounts <- accounts %>% sdf_repartition(78)
> dag <- spark_apply(accounts, get_dates, group_by = c("row"), 
+                    columns = list(row = "integer",
+                                   last_update_by = "character",
+                                   last_end_time = "character",
+                                   read_val = "numeric",
+                                   batch_id = "numeric",
+                                   fail_reason = "character",
+                                   end_time = "character",
+                                   meas_type = "character",
+                                   svcpt_id = "numeric",
+                                   org_id = "character",
+                                   last_update_date = "character",
+                                   validation_status = "character"
+                                   ))
> peak_usage <- dag %>% collect  
Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anon$1.next(SparkPlan.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anon$1.next(SparkPlan.scala:254)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anon$1.foreach(SparkPlan.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeCollect$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeCollect$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:275)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2778)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2351)
    at sparklyr.Utils$.collect(utils.scala:196)
    at sparklyr.Utils.collect(utils.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:102)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:97)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:62)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:52)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I have misread your example but the memory problem seems to occur when you collect and not when you use spark_apply. Try

```
config$spark.driver.maxResultSize <- XXX
```

where XXX is what you expect to need (I have set it to 4G for a similar job). See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html for further details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a GC problem, maybe you should try configuring your JVM with other arguments, are you using G1 as your GC? 
If you are not able to provide more memory and you have issues with the gc collect times, you should try using another JVM (maybe Zing from Azul systems?

Answer (score 0):

I've set the overhead memory needed for `spark_apply` using `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`. I've found that using the `by=` argument of `sfd_repartition` is useful and using the `group_by=` in `spark_apply` also helps. The more you are able to split up your data between executors the better.